# Does anybody know tools for custom time measurement/calendars?

Tags: time, software-recommendations

I work on software tool for making character's backgrounds/storylines. There may be a couple hundreds of PCs and NPCs with background events. One of the important part of the system is event concept. I use standard Gregorian calendar for events but in imaginary worlds it is not always well suitable.

I tried to find existing solution for custom calendar but without success.
How it should look like in my vision:

- possibility to specify different time measurement cycles
- visualize such calendar
- ideally it should generate timeline

Does anybody know something like this?

Comment: Would [Donjon's Calendar Generator](https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/calendar/) be of interest?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin but it only provides calendars for Earth, Eberron, Golarion, Greyhawk and "Random" - no option for own, custom one.

Comment: Check the settings on the other tabs - the predefines are there for common ones; you can set all of the parameters as you like. I'll concede that documentation is lacking, but a little bit of exploration will get you what you need.

Comment: Good point. It is possible to create simple Earth like calendars. Thanks)

Comment: The only issue, you may want to be aware of, is that Donjon's Calendar Generator doesn't have the option to include something like a leap year; each year on your calendar will always have the same number of days.

Comment: I think leap year is not a big problem in most cases. I worry about epochs. For example in the Lord of the Rings there are 4 epochs. There are also other problems with time measurement but measuring epochs is useful.

Comment: Software and resource recommendations for building a world are perfectly on-topic this question is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments before... [Donjon's Fantasy Calendar Generator](https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/calendar/) allows you to specify most of the "normal" information for a calendar (names and count of months, days per month, days per week and names, names and number of moons and lengths of their respective cycles). It is good for "single" calendars, like most Terrestrial cultures use; you would need to run it twice and manually combine the results if you wanted something like the Mayan *Tzolkin/Haab* combination. It doesn't handle intercalations (leap years), either. It will optionally add random celestial events, but they truly are random, and don't really match up with the other information provided (e.g., a lunar eclipse might appear on a date where the moon ostensibly being eclipsed isn't full or near-full).

FWIW, calling it a **Fantasy** calendar generator is a bit of a misnomer; there's nothing that "doesn't work" for using it in a SF context (e.g., the *Traveller* role-playing game).